# Constructor JSONObject(java.lang.String)

Tags: java, json

I am getting this compilation error:

> cannot find symbol Constructor JSONObject(java.lang.String)

Can any one explain what is wrong with it?

```
String jsnString = new String("{\"fname\":\"DKP\",\"lname\":\"patel\"}");
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(new String(jsnString));
```

I also tried with:

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(jsnString);
```

Comment: also I replaced JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(new String(jsnString)); with JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(jsnString);

Comment: What JSON library are you using? (ps: the second version is better, there is no need to create a new string like you do in the first one)

Comment: I am using json-lib-2.2.2-jdk15.jar

Comment: I just checked the javadoc and there is no JSONObject constructor that takes a String. There only is a no-argument constructor and another one that takes a boolean. Are you sure you are not mixing 2 different JSON libraries?

Comment: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: there are total 8 constructors as I see on above link

Comment: Not in the library you mentioned. You can download the javadoc [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/json-lib/files/json-lib/json-lib-2.2.2/) and check by yourself.

Comment: The javadoc you linked to in your comment seems to correspond to [this other library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java).

Comment: actually I found the solution but the other way, I used JSONObject jObj = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(jsnString); ...

Comment: You might consider using [a different library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library). I think Jackson works well.

Comment: yes... thats correct " assylias ".. thank you for your answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check to see if it is correctly linked and imported.  Can you use any of the other classes / static methods in the class?

Comment: yes, becoz when I use JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject("{\"fname\":\"DKP\",\"lname\":\"patel\"}"); , it is compiling without error..